# Multiple devices wordpress website

Tags: multisite, mobile

how can I create a wordpress website that has two contents version (images on mobile version  are different from desktop ones) and redirect visitors based on the device they are using.
The both contents version will use the same theme.

Comment: If contents are different then you may need to use two different installation or perhaps a multisite setup.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer @Sisir. But my main concern is how to detect visitors device or screen size and redirect them to the right content ?

Comment: What you are asking is hard to do efficiently and reliably. You are better off with media queries.

Comment: I see your point @s_ha_dum, I wonder how to target the element ot hide or show since I am not sure if the theme will give me control on Id's or classes

Comment: The theme has no choice but to give you control of its IDs and Classes. CSS starts with "cascading" for a reason.

Comment: You can use WP Touch plugin - very easy to use and works on the same URL.